# Create a loop in google-form

Tags: loops, google-apps-script, iteration, google-forms

I know absolutely anything about Google's apps-script and I found nothing corresponding to my problem. So I ask my question to the community and I hope someone can help me.

I've created a Google form in which I want to be able to ask the same question several times without having to validate the form and return to the beginning. In brief, make a loop, an iterative question.

Can somebody help me with this? 
I'm sorry for my English... Thanks.

Comment: The user can not be re-directed back to the same Form after clicking the Submit button.  All, you can do is click the link to submit another response.    Make sure that in the settings, the "Show respondents a link to:" section has "Submit another response" checked.

Comment: Do you want to repeat the entire form, or do you want to repeat a single question? An example of the latter would be a group of people, where you don't know how big the group is, but you want the e-mail addresses of the people in the group.